# AVAssetExport setting a constant frame rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video, avfoundation

I am using AVAssetExport to export a composition of asset tracks. But the problem is I can't get the Frame rate mode to be constant, the meta data for the video being exported is as follows:

**Video**
ID : 1
Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : Main@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames : 2 frames
Codec ID : avc1
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding
Duration : 3s 502ms
Bit rate : 684 Kbps
Width : 480 pixels
Height : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 1.000
Frame rate mode : Variable
Frame rate : 30.000 fps
Minimum frame rate : 28.571 fps
Maximum frame rate : 30.000 fps
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.099
Stream size : 292 KiB (90%)
Title : Core Media Video
Encoded date : UTC 2013-11-22 00:27:28
Tagged date : UTC 2013-11-22 00:27:32
Color primaries : BT.709
Transfer characteristics : BT.709
Matrix coefficients : BT.601

My code being used for the export is as follows:

```
AVAssetExportSession *session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
session.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalVideoPath];
session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
[session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch ([session status]) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            LogError(@"Export failed: %@", [session error]);
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            Log(@"Export canceled");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            Log(@"Export successfully");
            break;
        default:
            Log(@"Export session status unknown");
            break;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This means the asset being export has frame durations which are not constant. If the frames *all* have exactly the same duration, then you'll see the "Frame rate mode" reported as "Constant".